# Do a simple git pull or gh repo sync via Nginx (+Lua) in Windows 10

Tags: authentication, nginx, github, lua, webhooks

In Windows 10.

like all tough problems, I KNOW it should be quite
simple. It boils down to:

I can write .bat scripts, powershell scripts etc which all work fine to update the repo (git pull) when called from the command line.

But I absolutely cannot seem to configure git or hit upon the right syntax which will make the below work:

**In nginx:**

```
location /hooks {
    — some code BEFORE, all works fine 
    local handle = io.popen("cd path\\to\\my\\repo && gh repo sync --force")
    local output = handle:read("*all")
    handle:close()
    — some code AFTER, also works fine
}
```

I think it's got to be an authentication problem one way or another but I can't seem to get a lock on it.

When I run the code above, nothing — no characters at all — prints out to ngx.ERR in my log file. Everything else works fine.

Comment: What happens exactly when you run what you wrote? And what's in `output`?

Comment: @Joseph: I added that info to the question above. Pretty much nothing happens at all (that I can tell) for that code. In other words, `output` is probably `nil` within Lua. 

Here’s a thought- can I go to the repo in GitHub and get a record of every time the repo received a PULL request from anybody — regardless of whether it was successful?